# Object pointer doesn't work

Tags: c++, function, class, pointers

My task was to create an object in class, initialize it and output(using pointer to class). This code compiles perfectly, but the output doesn't appear. I would really appreciate any help, thank you in advance!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class family
{
public:
    void setWife(string w)
    {w = wife;};
    string getWife()
    {return wife;};
    void setHusband(string h)
    {husband = h;};
    string getHusband()
    {return husband;};
    void setSon(string s)
    {s  = son;};
    string getSon()
    {return son;};
    void setDaughter1(string d1)
    {d1  = daughter1;};
    string getDaughter1()
    {return daughter1;};
    void setDaughter2(string d2)
    {daughter2 = d2;};
    string getDaughter2()
    {return daughter2;};
    double* getPointer()
    {return &pointer;};
    void initialize()
    {
        setWife("Shirley Collin");
        setHusband("Donald Collin");
        setSon("Collin Collin");
        setDaughter1("Harriet Collin");
        setDaughter2("Hillary Collin");
    }
    friend void output(family* Collin);


private:
    string wife;
    string husband;
    string son;
    string daughter1;
    string daughter2;
    double pointer;
};


void output(family* Collin)
{cout << "Husband is " <<Collin->getHusband()<< endl;
    cout << "wife is " << Collin ->getWife() << endl;
    cout << "son is " << Collin->getSon() << endl;
    cout << "daughter1 is " << Collin->getDaughter1() << endl;
    cout << "daughter2 is " <<  Collin->getDaughter2()<< endl;
};

int main()
{family Collin;
    Collin.initialize();
    family *pointer = new family;
    output (pointer);
    cin.ignore();

}
```

Comment: I guess you want `output (&Collin);`.

Comment: Start with a much simpler class, get the pointer stuff working perfectly, then add all of the other stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
family Collin;
Collin.initialize();
```

This constructs an instance of the `family` class, and initializes it with the values defined in the `initialize()` method.

```
family *pointer = new family;
output (pointer);
```

This constructs a second instance of the `family` class, does not initialize it in any way, and calls the `output()` method, to display the contents of the completely uninitialized second instance of this `family` class.

This is why this program produces no useful output.

You probably want to replace these four lines with:

```
family *pointer=new family;
pointer->initialize();
output(pointer);
```

Comment: Great, 1  and last strings of output started working, I will try to fix leftovers, thank you!